# Prepend table element to list of data using Ajax and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to prepend a recently created post to a list without having to refresh the browser. I am wondering how this can be done with table elements.

#### index.html.erb

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Card image</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="content">
      <%= render @suggested_invites %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

#### _suggested_invite.html.erb

```
<% @suggested_invites.each do |suggested_invite| %>
    <tr style="background-color:<%= suggested_invite.color %>">
  <td style="color:white"><%= suggested_invite.name %></td>
  <td><img src="<%= suggested_invite.card_image %>" class="img-fluid" id="card_image" alt="Responsive image"></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_suggested_invite_path(suggested_invite), :class => 'action_buttons' %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'De-Activate', suggested_invite, method: :delete, :class => 'action_buttons', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

#### suggested_invites_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @suggested_invite = SuggestedInvite.new(suggested_invite_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @suggested_invite.save
        format.html { redirect_to @suggested_invite, notice: 'Suggested invite was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @suggested_invite }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @suggested_invite.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

#### create.js.erb

```
$("#mynewsuggestedinvite").modal('hide');
$("#content").prepend('<%= j render @suggested_invite %>');
```

When I run this code I get a 500 internal server error. I know that it breaks here:

```
$("#content").prepend('<%= j render @suggested_invite %>');
```

I have been looking and haven't found any ways of doing this. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you check your logs (terminal window or `log/development.log`) so we get more detail of what error you are getting? search for the 500 and look at the error message, and also the stacktrace and show us? Cheers.

Comment: So running this in a docker container so seeing logs isn't as easy as that unfortunately.

Comment: Ah... that's annoying. :/ Can you test it locally on development and see the same issue happening?

Answer (score 0):

To see which error you get, without access to logs you can do this:

```
begin
  $("#content").prepend('<%= j render @suggested_invite %>');
rescue Error => e
  <%= raw e.backtrace %>
end
```

Then check the server response when trying to create